# Custom error JSON in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, error-handling, ruby-on-rails-5

How do I render custom error JSON in a Rails 5 API? Right now, if I perform a GET on this url `http://localhost:3000/users/5`, it returns the 404 not found code, and all the traces associated with it. How can I stop Rails from automatically rendering all the traces?

Example of the generated error response: https://pastebin.com/C1dQA5eL

Comment: i think this link will work for u....https://wyeworks.com/blog/2016/1/12/improvements-to-error-responses-in-rails-5-api-mode

Comment: @amrit I have tried, by setting `config.consider_all_requests_local` to `false`. But that made Rails send an empty response as the error message

Comment: Are you able to rescue in `rescue` block?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon yes, but it feels kind of hacky, and I have to define 1 rescue block for each error as all the errors are different

Comment: @RavernKoh yeah, but my point was it is not a validation error, it is an `RecordNotFound` exception which should not be raised, even if it does, it should be handled gracefully rather than giving it to rails. one common way of doing it is using `.find_by_id()` instead of `.find`, former will return `nil` instead of throwing exception and then you can reply with `204` which is logical for this request than a `404`

Comment: Thanks. That is much more elegant. @Md.FarhanMemon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can create a custom module and extend it in your controller. Create a method in that module with parameters of resource and value. And on the basis of that send response and after that you can extend it in your respective Controller 
like this:

```
class MyController
  include AppError
end
```

Comment: @RavernKoh Hope it helps! If you find it useful please accept the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think you should `if....else`.

```
def show
  user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
  if user.present?
    render json: user
  else
    render json: { status: :not_found }
  end
end
```